# how to pass this keyword to javascript class functions

Tags: javascript, class, this

I'm running into the `undefinded` error when trying to access the `this.numberObject` from another function `init`.

I'm pretty sure it's because my `this` keyword is referencing the window object.

**My problem** is that I can't figure out an elegant way to structure my code.

**Current Code:**

```
class IncrementNumbers {
  constructor() {
    this.numberObject = document.querySelector(".incrementNum");
    if (this.numberObject != null) {
      console.log(this.numberObject.innerHTML);
      this.num = this.numberObject.innerHTML;
      this.events();
    }
  }

  events() {
    console.log("events function ran");
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let target = 345;
    let current = 0;
    function addOneToElement() {
      if (current === target) {
        clearInterval(addOne);
      }
      current++;
      this.numberObject.innerHTML = current; <---- ERROR HERE
    }
    let addOne = setInterval(addOneToElement, 10);
  }
}

export default IncrementNumbers;
```

**Error:**

```
IncrementNumbers.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

I can fix the error by adding in

```
  this.numberObject = document.querySelector(".incrementNum");
```

to the following function

```
init() {
    let target = 345;
    let current = 0;
    function addOneToElement() {
      this.numberObject = document.querySelector(".incrementNum");  <--- ADDED HERE
      if (current === target) {
        clearInterval(addOne);
      }
      current++;
      this.numberObject.innerHTML = current;
    }
    let addOne = setInterval(addOneToElement, 10);
  }
```

However this feels a bit redundant because I'm already referencing the element Object in my constructor. I'd like the function, `init` to run once the page has loaded.

Is there a better way?

Thank you

Comment: Change `this.init();` to `init.call(this)`.

Comment: You can either convert `addOneToElement` to an arrow function, or keep the non-arrow finction, but bind it to the this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to come from a misspropagation of the `this` object. 
In your function `init` you set a new function named `addOneToElement` that is called inside of a `setInterval`, this `setInterval` `instance` does not have access to the `this` element of your `class`.

To fix the problem you could try to do something like

```js
class IncrementNumbers {
  constructor() {
    this.numberObject = document.querySelector(".incrementNum");
    if (this.numberObject != null) {
      console.log(this.numberObject.innerHTML);
      this.num = this.numberObject.innerHTML;
      this.events();
    }
  }

  events() {
    console.log("events function ran");
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let target = 345;
    let current = 0;
    function addOneToElement() {
      if (current === target) {
        clearInterval(addOne);
      }
      current++;
      this.numberObject.innerHTML = current; // <---- ERROR HERE
    }
    let addOne = setInterval(addOneToElement.bind(this), 10);
  }
}

export default IncrementNumbers;
```

```js
let addOne = setInterval(addOneToElement.bind(this), 10);
```

Where you bind the `this` `instance` of your `class` to the function `addOneToElement`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the inner function `addOneToElement` that creates its own `this` context within init.

A simple fix would be to use arrow functions which don't have a this context:

```
class IncrementNumbers {
  init() {
    let target = 345;
    let current = 0;
    // Use an arrow function here.
    const addOneToElement = () => {
      if (current === target) {
        clearInterval(addOne);
      }
      current++;
      this.numberObject.innerHTML = current; <---- ERROR HERE
    }
    let addOne = setInterval(addOneToElement, 10);
  }
}
```

Another option would be to bind the this context to addOneToElement:

```
let addOne = setInterval(addOneToElement.bind(this), 10);
```